# Configuring non-restful routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I can't figure out how to do this in rails 3.0. I have a controller, `products`, and an action, `search`, and in `routes.rb` I've tried

```
resources :products, :collection => {:search => :post }
```

and

```
match 'products/search' => 'products#search', :via => [:get, :post]
```

and many other settings, but whenever I access `products/search` I still get an error complaining that the Product with id, `search`, can't be found for the action `show`. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're close.

```
resources :products do
  collection do 
    match 'search', :via => [:get, :post]
  end
end
```

Alternatively, you could also do:

```
resources :products do
  match 'search', :on => :collection, :via => [:get, :post]
end
```

See [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) of the Edge Guides for more information, more specifically:

- [2.9.2 Adding Collection Routes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes)
- [3.7 HTTP Verb Constraints](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints)

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I missed that section of the "routing from outside in" page. Awesome. Thanks, guys, that worked.

Comment: No prob. Glad we could help. =) It's too bad you can't mark both of ours as answers. =D

Answer (score 4):

In Rails 3, `collection` is now a block:

```
resources :products do
  collection do
    get :search
    post :search
  end
end
```

This will allow you to access the `ProductsController#search` action using either a `GET` or `POST` request.